# Synthesize in ISE for FSM is running too long

Tags: vhdl, synthesis

Essentially, I'm making a simple calculator, so I used a `FSM` to create a `BintoBCD` converter for the seven segment display. However, when it gets to the point in synthesis it runs for way too long. I'm not sure what the problems is and I would appreciate some help.

TOPFILE CODE BCD:

```
--BintoBCD port map
  bO <= "00" & qM;
  B0 : BintoBCD port map (clk => clk, reset => clr,  binary_in => bO, bcd0 => b1, bcd1 => b2, bcd2 => b3, bcd3 => b4, bcd4 => b5, bcd5 => b6, bcd6 => b7, bcd7 => b8, bcd8 => b9, bcd9 => b10);
```

CODE FOR FSM:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity BintoBCD is
port(clk, reset: in std_logic;
    binary_in: in std_logic_vector(35 downto 0);
    bcd0, bcd1, bcd2, bcd3, bcd4, bcd5, bcd6, bcd7, bcd8, bcd9 : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0));
end BintoBCD ;

architecture behaviour of BintoBCD is

type states is (start, shift, done);

signal state, state_next: states;

signal binary, binary_next: std_logic_vector(35 downto 0);

signal bcds, bcds_reg, bcds_next: std_logic_vector(39 downto 0);

signal bcds_out_reg, bcds_out_reg_next: std_logic_vector(39 downto 0);

signal shift_counter, shift_counter_next: natural range 0 to 36;

begin
process(clk, reset)
begin
    if reset = '1' then
        binary <= (others => '0');
        bcds <= (others => '0');
        state <= start;
        bcds_out_reg <= (others => '0');
        shift_counter <= 0;
    elsif falling_edge(clk) then
        binary <= binary_next;
        bcds <= bcds_next;
        state <= state_next;
        bcds_out_reg <= bcds_out_reg_next;
        shift_counter <= shift_counter_next;
    end if;
end process;

process(state, binary, binary_in, bcds, bcds_reg, shift_counter)
begin
    state_next <= state;
    bcds_next <= bcds;
    binary_next <= binary;
    shift_counter_next <= shift_counter;

    case state is
        when start =>
            state_next <= shift;
            binary_next <= binary_in;
            bcds_next <= (others => '0');
            shift_counter_next <= 0;
        when shift =>
            if shift_counter = 36 then
                state_next <= done;
            else
                binary_next <= binary(34 downto 0) & 'L';
                bcds_next <= bcds_reg(38 downto 0) & binary(35);
                shift_counter_next <= shift_counter + 1;
            end if;
        when done =>
            state_next <= start;
    end case;
end process;

 bcds_reg(39 downto 36) <= bcds(39 downto 36) + 3 when bcds(39 downto 36) > 4 else
                          bcds(39 downto 36);

 bcds_reg(35 downto 32) <= bcds(35 downto 32) + 3 when bcds(35 downto 32) > 4 else
                          bcds(35 downto 32);

 bcds_reg(31 downto 28) <= bcds(31 downto 28) + 3 when bcds(31 downto 28) > 4 else
                          bcds(31 downto 28);

 bcds_reg(27 downto 24) <= bcds(27 downto 24) + 3 when bcds(27 downto 24) > 4 else
                          bcds(27 downto 24);

 bcds_reg(23 downto 20) <= bcds(23 downto 20) + 3 when bcds(23 downto 20) > 4 else
                          bcds(23 downto 20);

bcds_reg(19 downto 16) <= bcds(19 downto 16) + 3 when bcds(19 downto 16) > 4 else
                          bcds(19 downto 16);

bcds_reg(15 downto 12) <= bcds(15 downto 12) + 3 when bcds(15 downto 12) > 4 else
                          bcds(15 downto 12);

bcds_reg(11 downto 8) <= bcds(11 downto 8) + 3 when bcds(11 downto 8) > 4 else
                         bcds(11 downto 8);

bcds_reg(7 downto 4) <= bcds(7 downto 4) + 3 when bcds(7 downto 4) > 4 else
                        bcds(7 downto 4);

bcds_reg(3 downto 0) <= bcds(3 downto 0) + 3 when bcds(3 downto 0) > 4 else
                        bcds(3 downto 0);

bcds_out_reg_next <= bcds when state = done else
                     bcds_out_reg;

 bcd9 <= bcds_out_reg(39 downto 36);
 bcd8 <= bcds_out_reg(35 downto 32);
 bcd7 <= bcds_out_reg(31 downto 28);                             
bcd6 <= bcds_out_reg(27 downto 24); 
 bcd5 <= bcds_out_reg(23 downto 20);
bcd4 <= bcds_out_reg(19 downto 16);
bcd3 <= bcds_out_reg(15 downto 12);
bcd2 <= bcds_out_reg(11 downto 8);
bcd1 <= bcds_out_reg(7 downto 4);
bcd0 <= bcds_out_reg(3 downto 0);

end behaviour;
```

Comment: I do not see any reason why this synthesis should take especially long. You could simplify your rather repetitive coding style using, e.g. a `generate for` statement, but this would not make a difference in terms of synthesis run time. Could it be that you are targeting a high end FPGA but run your synthesis on a low end computer with not enough memory? This could explain why it takes so long: swapping and swapping and swapping...

Comment: This is not a complete example. Only synthesizing this part does not seem to give the issue you describe. I.e. If we cannot reproduce your issue, we cannot help you.